# Possible to upgrade an existing ESXi Host Server (2 CPU sockets, 1 used) with a new, different CPU?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, central-processing-unit

I have a server which has 2 CPU Sockets and I used only one of the sockets so far. I have VMware ESXi V.6.0.0 installed and running.
I know that the free version supports 2 physical CPU, so in order to upgrade my physical machine, do I have to buy the exact same CPU again, or can I buy a newer/better/different CPU? 
I understand that I won't be able to create a machine using parts of both CPU's later on, but if I create only 2 VM's running both on one physical core, will this be possible?

Comment: Forget VMware, you shouldn't be mixing CPU's at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> do I have to buy the exact same CPU again?

If you want to run both the existing CPU *and* the new one then they have to be the exact same CPU.

> or can I buy a newer/better/different CPU?

You can put in a newer one if you pull out the old one.